# Redireccionar con js. Necesito crear otro archivo js o puedo trabajar en el mismo?

Tags: javascript, html

La pregunta es la siguiente estoy haciendo tipo un "cajero" (todo bastante precario es para practicar y tomarle la mano) y cuando la persona ingresa su usuario y contraseña apreta un boton de iniciar sesion (si el usuario es correcto)... mi idea es redireccionarla a una pagina que sea operaciones..pero seguir trabajando con el mismo archivo js... como hago para "separar" lo que tiene quee ejecutarse en la pagina principal de lo que tiene que ejecutarse en la pagina operaciones en el archivo js??? gracias!

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta tiene que ver con otra que habias hecho en el sitio, pero no tienen la misma respuesta... separar lo que tiene que ejecutarse en la pagina principal de lo que debe ejecutarse en la otra pagina??,  hay que preguntarse depronto que sentido quieres que tome ello... es decir segun dices lo rediriges a otra parte pero quieres seguir usando el script del mismo archivo inicial luego de que se le redirija.

Comment: No me tomes la palabra del todo porque soy consciente que aun me falta mucho por aprender y talvez no soy del todo consciente o no estoy entendiendo bien que es lo que deseas hacer, pero en mi opinion, creo que es mejor separar en 2 paginas aquello que deseas hacer, es decir, tu ya tienes las dos paginas segun entiendo, pero el script a la vez tambien dividirlo en 2, es decir, en una parte solo hacer algo, y en el otro de la otra pagina hacer lo otro.

Comment: Lo que yo quiero hacer es esto.. que se ejecute el fragmento de codigo SOLAMENTE en la pagina redireccionada me explico? quiero una condicion que detecte que estoy en la pagina redireccionada entonces alli adentro ejecutar el codigo correspondiente! Y claro que lo tomo! tambien pense en dividirlo en dos archivos js, pero no se cual de las dos practicas es la "mas" correcta

Comment: Porfavor no grites, se escucha asi, por otra parte, si deseas una 'condicion' que ejecute tu codigo en la pagina redireccionada, se puede lograr por medio de POST puesto que los datos son sensibles o por lo menos eso parece... asi que en este caso conviene mejor usar POST que GET (ojo, esto de poner mayusculas es costumbre, normalmente escribo los metodos en mayusculas, no por nada mas), entonces una forma de recuperar tus datos es usando PHP para recogerlos y hacer procesos con JS.

Comment: Entre esos datos puedes enviar una variable condicion que te ayude a determinar si haz llegado hasta esa pagina por el producto de una redireccion (hay datos), o si enrealidad fue por otro motivo (no ejecutar el codigo), es una condicion simple que se puede poner en el codigo para poder hacer lo que deseas de acuerdo si se trata de una redireccion o no...

Comment: El problema viene es si no deseas o no se puede usar PHP para recoger esos datos... en ese caso tendriamos que recurrir al metodo GET puesto que con este se pueden recoger los datos directamente desde JS pero el hecho de usar GET destruiria la seguridad automaticamente, puesto que GET normalmente es usado para enviar cosas irrelevantes, cosas que el usuario puede ver y que no comprometen la seguridad si se cambian o ven (por ejemplo el indice de una pagina).

Answer (score 0):

la mejor opción es separar el js para cada una de las paginas, sin embargo si quieres usar alguna función que tienes en otro archivo, solo tienes que importarla del documento, por ejemplo.

```
import { miFuncion } from './miArchivo.js'
```

o puedes utilizar

```
const miFuncion = require('./miArchivo.js')
```

Toma en cuenta que para importarla del documento tendrás que exportarla.

miArchivo.js

```
function miFuncion(){...}

export {miFuncion}
```

Y esto seria todo, así podrías usarla donde quieras.